# should I move my completed site from it's subdomain to it's own hosting? Will it hurt SEO

Tags: seo, web-hosting, subdomain

I have one hosting account and about 11 domains. The domains are completely individual not having content, topic or themes in common, 11 indidivual domains and websites.

To save some cash up front I created subdomains each website/domain is on a subdomain using the one hosting account. People access the sites through their own URL's (www.bedbugsnorthwest.com, www.solartravel.net) etc.

Would it be better for the sites for SEO to each have their own individual hosting account and not be a subdomain of the main account www.oldrockers.org? Thanks.

Comment: could you clarify-- when you say "subdomain" do you mean the technical definition of a subdomain?  In other words, currently your 11 websites have URL's such as begbugsnorthwest.oldrockers.org and solartravel.oldrockers.org.  Or are you using subdomain to mean that these are sub accounts of your primary hosting account and may used shared IP's, but they all have distinct domains of their own?

Answer (score 7):

What you're describing aren't [subdomains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). And there's absolutely no reason to maintain separate hosting accounts for each domain.

It won't hurt SEO to switch to a different hosting account or even a new web host, but what benefits do you hope to gain from managing 11 different hosting accounts?

There's a reason why web hosts allow you to operate multiple sites on a single account. An account is simply a way to provide access to services. It's a set of login credentials that let you access their control panel and network services, and it's a way to encapsulate services rendered for accounting purposes.

Unless each site belongs to a separate business that needs to be separated for accounting purposes, or their login credentials need to be unique for security reasons, there's no reason to move them to separate accounts.